# How to set vertex colors on import

Tags: python, mesh, import

I have a python based importer and I can successfully import meshes with uv's and normals. Now I am trying the vertex colors, but I ran into an issue.

I use this to create the the vertex color:

```
vertex_color_layer0 = mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer0')
```

but then when I try to set a vertex color, I get this error

```
vertex_color_layer0.data[i].color = (c[0],c[1],c[2],c[3])
RuntimeError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: internal error, valid index
0 given in 172178 sized collection, but value not found
```

When I try the same thing in an interactive session, it works fine, it's just in the import code it fails.

I am able to make it work by looping for times:

```
    # not sure why we cant do this in one loop.... 
    vertex_color_layer0 = mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer0',do_init=False)
    for i, c in enumerate(data.colors):
        vertex_color_layer0.data[i].color = (c[3],c[3],c[3],c[3])
        
    vertex_color_layer1 = mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer1',do_init=False)
    for i, c in enumerate(data.colors):
        vertex_color_layer1.data[i].color = (c[0],c[0],c[0],c[0])
   
    vertex_color_layer2 = mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer2',do_init=False)
    for i, c in enumerate(data.colors):
        vertex_color_layer2.data[i].color = (c[1],c[1],c[1],c[1])
   
    vertex_color_layer3 = mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer3',do_init=False)
    for i, c in enumerate(data.colors):
        vertex_color_layer3.data[i].color = (c[2],c[2],c[2],c[2])
```

but not in a single loop, that gives me the error above:

```
    vertex_color_layer0 = mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer0',do_init=False)
    vertex_color_layer1 = mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer1',do_init=False)
    vertex_color_layer2 = mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer2',do_init=False)
    vertex_color_layer3 = mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer3',do_init=False)

    for i, c in enumerate(data.colors):
        vertex_color_layer0.data[i].color = (c[3],c[3],c[3],c[3])
        vertex_color_layer1.data[i].color = (c[0],c[0],c[0],c[0])
        vertex_color_layer2.data[i].color = (c[1],c[1],c[1],c[1])
        vertex_color_layer3.data[i].color = (c[2],c[2],c[2],c[2])
```

But ideally I would want to loop over the colors only once.

Any thoughts on how I could make this work?

Thanks,
Koen

Comment: Post your code. Possibly the reference is getting invalidated so you could try and see if mesh.vertex_colors['layer0'].data[i].color = ... works.

Comment: thanks I'll try that, I added the code to the original post that caused the error.

Comment: Would you want to use a smaller file instead of 172,178 vertices one? It might be some memory reallocate when you create multiple Blender array at once. The previous pointer to the array might have been changed due to the size reallocate for later entries

Comment: Yeah, each new invalidates the old references. See http://developer.blender.org/T43332#294071 for an example of how to do it.

Comment: thanks all, that was very usefull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work if you do it like...

```py
mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer0',do_init=False)
mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer1',do_init=False)
mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer2',do_init=False)
mesh.vertex_colors.new(name='layer3',do_init=False)

vertex_color_layer0 = mesh.vertex_colors['layer0']
vertex_color_layer1 = mesh.vertex_colors['layer1']
vertex_color_layer2 = mesh.vertex_colors['layer2']
vertex_color_layer3 = mesh.vertex_colors['layer3']

for i, c in enumerate(data.colors):
    vertex_color_layer0.data[i].color = (c[3],c[3],c[3],c[3])
    vertex_color_layer1.data[i].color = (c[0],c[0],c[0],c[0])
    vertex_color_layer2.data[i].color = (c[1],c[1],c[1],c[1])
    vertex_color_layer3.data[i].color = (c[2],c[2],c[2],c[2])
```